# React-Native : Running on JS Thread

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

How do i execute code in react-native's JS thread in iOS?

I am able to do same in react-native android by accessing reactApplicationContext.

**In Android** :

```
reactApplicationContext.runOnJSQueueThread(new Runnable() {
  public synchronized void run() {
    //enter code here
  }
});
```

**In IOS** : ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it after little digging into React-Native library.
Found the **executeBlockOnJavaScriptQueue** method in RCTJSCExecutor:

```
  [mRCTJSCExecutor executeBlockOnJavaScriptQueue:^{
      //enter your code
  }];
```